# Passing data in URL vs submitting via form using GET

Tags: php, html, forms, url-encoding

I have written a small php (test.php) that reads and displays the data passed to it.

`<?php $name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;?>`

When I execute the following URL
`http://localhost/test.php?name=Géo`

The text that gets displayed is: G�o

However, when I submit "Géo" from another webpage:

`<form method="get" action="test.php">
<input type="test" name="name">
<input type="Submit">
</form>`

the URL changes to `http://localhost/test.php?name=G%C3%A9o`

and now the correct text is displayed:Géo

In the first scenario, only when I add utf8_encode( $_GET['name']),  the correct text (Géo) gets displayed.

My question:
Is it possible to know how the data was passed, submitting via a form or directly from the URL. If not then what changes should I make to the webpage so that both the scenarios are handled correctly i.e. display Géo in both the cases.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the **second** scenario, the addition `utf8_encode( $_GET['name'] )` changes the input?

Comment: Adding utf8_encode to the second scenario changes the input to: GÃ©o

Comment: What is your "Content-Type" header? its contains something like `charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **reg. expression** that will check if the parameter contain `%`. Because that the encoded parameter probably contains a `%`.

But, if you'll execute url that for some reason contains a `%`, the problem will comeback...

Comment: Probably dont cares about execute without html form.

Comment: See Google, type in Géo or % in the search box and then change the URL to https://www.google.com?q=% or https://www.google.com?q=Géo In both the scenarios correct data is spit out.